# Java Wildfly POST method multipart/form-data: "Unable to get boundary..."

Tags: java, python-3.x, wildfly, multipartform-data, resteasy

I got a problem with a post method in java:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String testing(MultipartFormDataInput input)
{
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    String name = this.getFormValue(uploadForm, "name");

    List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");
...
}
```

The listing shows the start of the POST method, which consumes a file and several other parameters like "name". Everything is working fine as long as I provide some parameters and the file as input.
I also want to provide some output with the same method if there is no file provided. But in this case, I always get this **error**:

> java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for
>   multipart

This is even the case if I manually set the content header of the request to multipart/form-data.
Is there any solution to handle both use cases (params + file and only params) with one single POST method?

Thanks for the help!

**Client code in python:**

```
payload = {"name": "test"}
file = {"file": open("test.zip", "rb")}
url = "http://localhost:8080/test_war/test/test"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=file)
print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Comment: the error is in your client code. can you post that?

Comment: Added client code. By now I solved my problem with a second Post method with the same @Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the client library you are using:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/bedd9284c9646e50c10b3defdf519d4ba479e2c7/requests/models.py#L503

This line is making the assumption that if you pass files then it is a multi-part request, with no files it does something else.

Adding a fake file with a different parameter name should satisfy your server-side code:

```js
file_name ="test.zip"
if file_name:
    files = {"file": open("test.zip", "rb")}
else:
    files = {"dummy_file": "nothing"}
url = "http://localhost:8080/test_war/test/test"
r = requests.post(url, data={"name": "test"}, files=files)
print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just find it a bit strange that I also got the error if I manually set the content type to multipart/data-form.
Edit: stupid mistake, I have written "content-type" with capital C Oo